# How to convert the contents of a cell array into specific numbers?

Tags: matrix, cell-array

I want to convert the contents of column 1 in a cell array into specific numbers as mentioned in the code but doesn't work.

```
col=1;  
     [row_patho,col_patho]=size(data);
     for i=1:1:row_patho
     if Pro_patho_data{i,col}>=70
       Pro_patho_data(i,col)=11;  
     end
     end
```

Input:

73   t2b     7

59   t1c     9

58    t3b    7

83    t3b   8

wanted_output:

11   t2b     7

59   t1c     9

58    t3b    7

11    t3b   8

Comment: Pro_patho_data{i,col}=11;

Comment: @Jiss Raphel, I tried it but no number changed!

Comment: hi anyone can help me!